# Calculate Consecutive Concurrent Calls SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, count, unpivot

I just have the basic SQL skills hoping someone can help me out. I am using SQL Server trying to come up with a query to calculate consecutive concurrent calls happening at the same time per day. My company only has the license for 300 concurrent calls and were trying to find out the max point we reach per day. Basically if 3 people are on a call at 9:00 am and all 3 calls end at 9:15 the count would be 3. if another call happens at 9:05 am and ends at 9:20 am the count is now 4,but at 9:16 am the count would only be 1 then

I have a table (`conferencecall2`) with following columns:

```
CallID, UniqueCallID, Jointime, Leavetime
```

We get about 5000-6000 calls per day

Below is sample of some data.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The key here is to have (or generate) a table with one row for each time period.  Then it's a simple APPLY or scalar subquery:

```
select t.minute, c.calls
from time_table_with_one_row_per_minute t
cross apply
(
  select count(*) calls
  from calls c
  where t.Minute >= c.JoinTime
    and t.Minute <= c.LeaveTime
) c
```

Comment: where do i add the table im pulling from? sorry just have very basic sql skills

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by unpivoting the columns, then using window functions:

```
select x.call_time, sum(sum(x.cnt_calls)) over(order by x.call_time) as cnt
from conferencecall2 c
cross apply (values (c.jointime, 1), (c.leavetime, -1)) as x(call_time, cnt_calls)
group by x.call_time
```

This solution scans the table only once, so I would expect it to perform efficiently over a large dataset.

---

**Edit**: you can get the peak of concurent calls per day with another level of subquery:

```
select convert(date, call_time) as call_day, max(cnt) as peak_cnt
from (
    select x.call_time, sum(sum(x.cnt_calls)) over(order by x.call_time) as cnt
    from conferencecall2 c
    cross apply (values (c.jointime, 1), (c.leavetime, -1)) as x(call_time, cnt_calls)
    group by x.call_time
) c
group by convert(date, call_time)
```

---

**Edit 2**

If you want to filter, then you need to do that in the outer query:

```
select convert(date, call_time) as call_day, max(cnt) as peak_cnt
from (
    select x.call_time, sum(sum(x.cnt_calls)) over(order by x.call_time) as cnt
    from conferencecall2 c
    cross apply (values (c.jointime, 1), (c.leavetime, -1)) as x(call_time, cnt_calls)
    group by x.call_time
) c
where call_time >= @endtime and call_time < @endtime
group by convert(date, call_time)
```

Comment: when i try this i get an error. Does Not recognize a few of the choices ...x.call_time ,cnt_calls, and the order is highlighted as an error

Comment: @AdamRogers15: I fixed a few typos.

Comment: that worked, however i am receiving negative values to start some of the days, do you know what that would be possible? also i added a where close to just filter by 1 of  the days, is there an easier way to break it down by max number per day so i only see : todays date and max number, yesterday date and max number

Comment: @AdamRogers15: the query *as it is* cannot generate negative numbers. If you want to filter, then you need to do it in an outer query (not in the query itself), otherwise calls that happen across day boundaries are counted as `-1` (I guess that's what's happening here). See my update for how to get the daily peak.

Comment: yes i can see some of the negative are in the beginning of the day due to the fact that the calls from the night haven't ended yet. however when i run this last correction for the max per day, there is a negative numbers for some of the days for max, can you see a possible error in the script?

Comment: @AdamRogers15: as I said. If you want to filter, do no dot it in the same scope as the window function. Do that in the outer scope.

Comment: GMB: apologies, can you please show me what you mean? i copied the Edit: you wrote above, where would i put the outer scope then

Comment: would you be able to show me what you mean by putting it in the outer scope. if i put the  single date in a where clause it gives me correct answer but if i put in multiple dates it starts subtracting from the number

Comment: this still subtracts numbers from the total per day. It also produces negative numbers when the number is low for the day. Not sure where the subtraction is coming from.

Comment: any idea why the subtraction is only happening when i try and add in a series of dates?

Comment: @AdamRogers15: I don't know what you are saying. Are you able to provide a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: when i run the the original answer you posted, i input a where clause with just one date(2020-12-05 00:00:01 - 2020-12-06 00:00:00), and it outputs the correct amount of consecutive calls (19) for just the day. when i use edit2 you posted and use a time frame of (2020-12-01 - 2020-12-09) the answer is now (6) ..and its for all numbers not just one, it will subtract some calls from every number except the last number in the date. if you want to email me i can send you the script and answers from mssql, not sure how to input it in here. adam.rogers@nyulangone.org

Comment: @AdamRogers15: you can create a test case in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/), as I commented already.

Comment: is there another way? there are millions of of lines, to create the db on there would take a little. my sql db comes directly from the phone system

Comment: @AdamRogers15: you would need to build a minimum reproducible example that demonstrates the problem. That's a also the first step towards solving the problem yourself...